How to get tag in Dialogflow CX flexible webhook
I am trying to make a webhook call which would have the webhook tag and some other data.
I am trying to use flexible webhook and pass the data myself, how do I get hold of it to send it to the backend?
{
  "session_id": "$request.session-id",
  "intent_id": "$request.fulfillment.tag"
}

I tried this and this wouldn't work but that is what the documentation here says.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Hi @Dilip Badal, Could you elaborate on the issue, by providing more details of the issue, also provide the documentation if you have used any ?

@DhirajSingh Thank you for the reply, heres the issue.
When I make a call webhook call, I can set a webhook tag in dialogflow cx, when using flexible webhook, we have to send every param ourselves but I have no idea on how to get hold of that value. I did go through the documentation and some other resources and nothing helped so far. I have linked the documentation in my original post.

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

You can send the value using the json, please refer the screenshot of webhook :
appointmentId is the variable which will be containing the value of dxCode (it is a parameter i have created in the agent).
When the request will be sent to the API (URL specified in webhook), it will be sent in form of a request template  in which this "appointmentId" will be part of the json of the request. Please refer to the dialogflow cx documentation section in which webhook request format is provided.
Also, after implementing the logic on the "appointmentId" value, you can send the desired response back to webhook using the specified format in the document for response.
Let me know  if more details are required.
